# Flume-ng agent not starting and giving nullpointer exception

Tags: flume

I am writing custom source sink and channel and my config file is like

```
agent.sources = source
agent.sinks = sink
agent.channels = channel
agent.sources.source.type = com.flume.FlumeSource
agent.sources.source.channels = channel
agent.channels.channel.type = com.flume.FlumeChannel$Builder
agent.channels.channel.type = file
agent.sinks.sink.type = com.flume.FlumeSink
agent.sinks.sink.hdfs.path = <hdfs path>
agent.sources.source.channels = channel
agent.sinks.sink.channel = channel
```

I am trying to start the agent by adding the jar to the flume classpath using the command

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file flume.config --classpath /usr/lib/flume-ng/agent.jar --name nab-agent -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console`
```

It says the hdfs path is not present where as it exists. It gives `NullPointerException` saying hostname does not exist. and main class is not found in `org.apache.flume.node.Application`

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? What is the directory structure of the location you are running from?

Comment: I am now able to start the agent...anyways thanks Sarge